# Embed M3U8 joomla 3

Tags: joomla, playlist, m3u8, iptv

i have some IPTV urls as (Playliste) .M3U8 .tsformat like this:
http://123.345.543/live/abcd/123456.m3u8
http://123.345.543/abcd/123456.ts

I trying Allvideos Player component and many other player plugin without success...
Please someone can called any extension or plugin can play this type of files
thank you

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please take the [tour].  I am sorry to say that your question is very hard to understand. On top of that, the vague impression I get suggests that is is offtopic.

Answer (score 0):

If you are saying that you can't play the above streams using the HTML5  tag, then, yes, this is expected behaviour at this time.

To play HLS and DASH video streams on a web browser you typically would use a Javascript player like Dash.js, BitMovin, Shaka player etc.

You can see example players which will allow you test the streams here:

- http://dashif.org/reference/players/javascript/1.4.0/samples/dash-if-reference-player/
- https://bitmovin.com/hls-fragmented-mp4/
- https://shaka-player-demo.appspot.com